# Fit the table into the page

Tags: tables, longtable, fit, xtable

I am trying to fit this table into the page but unfortunately it is not working. The problem is, it is a supplemantry table, so I am using:

```
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Table},fileext=lst,listname={List of Supplementary Tables}]{supptable}
```

And then:

```
\begin{supptable}[bp]
\rotatebox{90}{
\vbox{
\begin{tabularhtx}{\textwidth}{\textheight}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
 &\textbf{DACHS} & \textbf{QUASAR} & \textbf{TCGA} & \textbf{NLCS} & \textbf{YCR-BCIP} & \textbf{DUSSEL} & \textbf{MECC} & \textbf{UMM} & \textbf{MUNICH}\\ 
 \hline
 Origin & Germany & United Kingdom & United States & The Netherlands & United Kingdom & Germany & Israel & Germany & Germany \\
 \hline
\end{tabularhtx}
\caption{Test supplementary table 1}
\label{supplTable1}
}
}
\end{supptable}
```

I need to shift the table. Can you please help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

- You should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document, which reproduce your problem
- From your code fragment is not possible to figured out your page layout, so In MWE below is anticipated that for document class is used `\article` and for pages layout default settings of the `geometry` package.
- For your table I would use

  - landscape page orientation
  - `tabularray` package for table
  - `\small` font size
  - reduced column separation width (3pt)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Table},
                            fileext=lsst,
                            listname={List of Supplementary Short Tables},
                            within=section, placement=htbp!]{supptable}

\begin{document}

\listofsupptables
\clearpage

\begin{landscape}
       \begin{supptable}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c, m]*{9}{X[c, m]} },
             colsep  = 2pt,
             row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries}
             }
        & DACHS     & QUASAR    & TCGA  & NLCS  & YCR-BCIP  
        & DUSSEL    & MECC      & UMM   & MUNICH    \\
Origin  & Germany   & United Kingdom 
                                & United States 
                                        & The Netherlands 
                                                & United Kingdom 
        & Germany   & Israel & Germany & Germany    \\
\end{tblr}
\captionof{table}{Test supplementary table 1}
\label{supplTable}

    \end{supptable}
\lipsum[66]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]